# Extract XML data from BLOB column in HANA

Tags: sql, database, blob, hana

I want to apply the HANA function [`XMLEXTRACT`](https://help.sap.com/viewer/7c78579ce9b14a669c1f3295b0d8ca16/Cloud/en-US/f1045c62108c449a835adba32c279090.html) to a `BLOB` column of a table containing an `UTF8` encoded XML document.

In the concrete example, I have a database table `zprc_prot_cont` with a column named `content` of datatype `BLOB`, and I want to extract the text content of the first `<AKTNR>` element in the XML document which is contained in that column. Since by its documentation the function `XMLEXTRACT` only applies to arguments of datatype `CLOB`, `NCLOB`, `VARCHAR`, or `NVARCHAR`, but not to type `BLOB`, some conversion is necessary. But which is the right one?

I tried conversion functions like `cast()` or `to_clob()` but with no success:

```
select xmlextract( to_clob( content ), '//AKTNR/text()' ) as aktnr 
  from zprc_prot_cont
```

The answer is

> SQL-ERROR 266: inconsistent datatype: BLOB is invalid for function
>   to_clob: line 1 col ...

Comment: Which table is it? And what application has written data into it?

Comment: @LarsBr. The table name is `zprc_prot_cont`. The BLOB contains an XML document in the form of an UTF8 encoded byte string.

Comment: So, that’s a custom-built table. Since there is no general BLOB->CLOB or string conversion possible, the application needs to take care of that. Can you change the column type to CLOB and reload the data? If there’s really only strings stored in it, that would be the better option anyhow.

Comment: @LarsBr. 1) An XML document in the ABAP stack is usually serialized as an `XSTRING` (containing the UTF8 data), not `STRING`. Datatype `XSTRING` by default will be mapped to `BLOB` by the DDIC when creating a database table.  
2) "there is no general BLOB->CLOB or string conversion possible" - not "general", clearly, but I would expect something like an UTF8 decoder in a HANA system.

Comment: There is a "decoder" for UTF-8 - all the TO_NVARCHAR()/TO_BLOB() functions do just that. In this case, you ask the DB to "decode" an arbitrary byte string and that's not allowed. You can always try to convert by using `BINTOSTR` - as you found already yourself. This may or may not fail, but at least you are aware of what you're doing and can understand why the conversion fails (if it does).

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself. The required function to make the `BLOB` column work as argument for `XMLEXTRACT` is the composition of `to_varbinary` with `bintostr`:

```
select 
  xmlextract( bintostr( to_varbinary( content ) ), 
              '(//MATNR)[1]/text()' ) 
    as matnr
  from zprc_prot_content
  where ...
```

A *caveat*: If the `XPath` expression yields no result, the function `xmlectract` aborts with error, in conformance with the documentation (I would have expected a `null` value as result).

Comment: The remarks are of course just your opinion. There are good arguments to not mix up type-casting with a high likelyhood of conversion failures with a function that is defined over text only. The same goes for the error instead of `NULL` return - `NULL` is not a value and your preference to simply ignore missing structures in the XML document is not a generally shared preference.

Comment: @Lars Br. A function that evaluates an XPath expression on an XML fragment may yield an empty result set. This is simply a possible result of the evaluation. In usual implementations this is not treated as an error.